# How to scroll to first incomplete object from a list of objects

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UITableView` which is populated with an array of questions. When I check a question I want to scroll to first incomplete question from my list. So if I check question 1, after I check question 10, I want to scroll me to question 2 because is incomplete.
How can I achieve this ?
Here is a link with my progress for the moment: https://github.com/tygruletz/ChecklistScrollDown

Here is a part of my code:

```
// Get all the values from the ChecklistCell using the delegates
extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistCellDelegate{  

    // Check if user pressed Pass or Fail btn for Vehicle/Trailer and scroll to next question
    func tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons(vehiclePassBtn: UIButton, vehicleFailBtn: UIButton, trailerPassBtn: UIButton, trailerFailBtn: UIButton, selectedCell: ChecklistCell) {

        let indexPath = questionsTableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell)!
        let item = itemSections[indexPath.section].checklistItems[indexPath.row]

        // Only Vehicle available
        if item.showVehicle && !item.showTrailer {

            if vehiclePassBtn.isSelected {
                item.vehiclePass = item.PASS
                item.isComplete = 1

                scrollDown(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
            }
            else if vehicleFailBtn.isSelected {
                item.vehiclePass = item.FAIL
                item.isComplete = 1

                scrollDown(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
            }
        }

            // Only Trailer available
        else if item.showTrailer && !item.showVehicle{

            if trailerPassBtn.isSelected {
                item.trailerPass = item.PASS
                item.isComplete = 1
                scrollDown(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
            }
            else if trailerFailBtn.isSelected {
                item.trailerPass = item.FAIL
                item.isComplete = 1
                scrollDown(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
            }
        }

            // Both available: Vehicle and Trailer
        else if item.showVehicle && item.showTrailer {

            if vehiclePassBtn.isSelected {
                item.vehiclePass = item.PASS
            }
            else if vehicleFailBtn.isSelected {
                item.vehiclePass = item.FAIL
            }
            if trailerPassBtn.isSelected {
                item.trailerPass = item.PASS
            }
            if trailerFailBtn.isSelected {
                item.trailerPass = item.FAIL
            }
        }

        if (item.vehiclePass == 1 || item.vehiclePass == 2) && (item.trailerPass == 1 || item.trailerPass == 2) {

            item.isComplete = 1
            scrollDown(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
        }

        print("Completed Questions: \(itemSections.map{$0.checklistItems.map {$0.isComplete}})")
        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Function to scroll down to next row when the user complete a question
    func scrollDown(row: Int, section: Int){

        let lastRowFromSection = questionsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1
        let lastSection = questionsTableView.numberOfSections - 1
        let lastRowFromLastSection = questionsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection) - 1

        itemSections.forEach {
            let firstIncompleteQuestion = $0.checklistItems.first(where: {$0.isComplete == 0}) // I can't manage to display only the first questions from list, at the moment I display the first incomplete questions from each section. I need somehow to find the first incomplete question from all sections and to scroll to that question.

            print("\n\nFirst incomplete question from list: \(firstIncompleteQuestion?.descript)")
            print("Scroll to first incomplete question from list !")
        }


        // I think all below rows need to be removed and to create a single condition to scroll to first incomplete question every time.

        // Not last Row and Not Last Section -> scroll to next row from the same section
        if row != lastRowFromSection && section != lastSection {
            questionsTableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: row + 1, section: section) as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }

        // Last Row but Not Last Section -> scroll to first Row from next Section
        if row == lastRowFromSection && section != lastSection {
            questionsTableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: section + 1) as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }

        // Not Last Row but Last Section -> scroll to next row from last section
        if row != lastRowFromLastSection && section == lastSection {
            questionsTableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: row + 1, section: section) as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }

        // Last Row from Last Section -> scroll to first row from first section
        if row == lastRowFromLastSection && section == lastSection {
            questionsTableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }

        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is a capture of screen:

[image]

Thanks for trying to help me !

Comment: you need to find an `object at an index` of unchecked object and scroll index position using the `table view `. `self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: first, at: .middle, animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```swift
var indexPath:[IndexPath] = []
for section in 0..<self.tableView.numberOfSections {
    for row in 0..<self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
        guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(
                at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as? MyCellType else {
            return
        }
        if myCheck { // do your check here
            indexPath.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
        }
    }
}
if let first = indexPath.first {
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: first, at: .middle, animated: true)
}
```